# Jquery auto scroll to div + X pixels

Tags: jquery, scroll

I use this code but not working. I want to auto scroll to div + 275px on page load with jquery. What's the problem?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Handler for .ready() called.
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#widenavdiv').offset() + 275px.top
    }, 'slow');
});
```

Comment: `scrollTop: $('#widenavdiv').offset().top + 275`

Comment: Always check your console for errors - your code will be giving a syntax error